# Google Domains subdomain forward not taking port

Tags: browser, port-forwarding, ddns

I have a ddns at http://hawkardalaskan.mynetgear.com, a domain at williamsiv.com, and I have FoundryVTT (sets up a web server of sorts) setup and running on a server that the DDNS points to. I setup a subdomain forward of dnd.williamsiv.com to http://hawkardalaskan.mynetgear.com, and I have port forwarding setup for 30000.

When I go to http://hawkardalaskan.mynetgear.com:30000, I'm able to login to FoundryVTT. When I go to http://dnd.williamsiv.com:30000 it will eventually time out and say site can't be reached. I've even slapped on the /join that gets automatically put there. Am I missing a step? I've done this with game servers plenty of times with several domains and ports, it was always this simple. Is there something different in a browser that isn't forwarding the port?